# Can't figure out what is causing this crash... EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I never had this crash occur on me personally, but it has affected a couple of users of the app where the crash would occur numerous times.

It's an iPad app and I'm trying to figure out what is causing this issue.

Basically the line is where the flight number label is displayed. The label text is taken from a localized strings file which has a string similar to "Flight %d". There is nothing wrong with the strings files and the data is taken from a flights NSArray. The odd thing is that this occurs before a flight search meaning that this crash occurs without any kind of input from the Internet. It is simply select a multicity flight from the type of flights, add a flight, remove a flight, select a date... it does checks to make sure that there are at least two flights and checks for a from and to airport code for each.

[Crash log on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WuHwkLbr)

Comment: It will be hard to debug without the code...

Comment: Post the code for your `MultiCityTicketController update` method and point out line 65. From the crash report you are most likely passing a `nil` pointer to the `stringWithFormat` call.